# What WPF control to use for a series of images (like Netflix, Hulu, etc..)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

New to .Net and Visual Studio. Quickly learning. As my first application, I am building a program similar to Netflix and Hulu (without the streaming part). Coming from a web background, I'd use tables and divs to accomplish what I am trying to do.

What component would I use to create a series of thumbnails (as you would find on Netflix) of the movie / TV show. Provided an image below as an example.

[image: example of netflix grid]

It would continue on with horizontal scroll. I understand this would be non trivial and I'm not expecting a direct answer. However, I am resourceful person and only would need to be pointed in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest a Grid. Get a table-like layout easily.

Comment: I think you should use windows store apps instead of WPF!

You can define thumbnail and methods and use async and await for loading your thumbnails

Comment: @nik Are you referring the App Studio that allows you to deploy applications within minutes? I feel though this may be very restrictive down the line. Pros and Cons WPF vs App Studio?

Comment: No, really my mean is Windows Store Apps for example using c# with xaml. and use one of templates such as Hub Apps or Split App or Blank Apps

Comment: To save yourself time of the look and feel of the UI, I would use MahApps. You can install it from a nuget package, it's really easy to use and it makes your apps look awesome! http://mahapps.com/

Comment: @DanielHakimi Thank you for the suggestion! Actually, I was using MahApps originally and switched to ModernUI as it conformed more towards the look I was aiming for. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `ItemsControl` variant which could be `ListView` with `ScrollViewer`.

Or, a `WrapPanel` with `ScrollViewer`.

Or, a `UniformGrid`.

Apply scrolling support using `Animation`.